# Trigger JSON response via Trait in Controller Larael

Tags: laravel, traits, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8 to build an API, I have a route which for the purposes of the question is... `/api/fact` which GETs a random fact. I have a `FactsController.php` file and two traits, **one** for constructing a JSON response, the **other** for getting a fact. For some reason when calling the trait's function from within my controller (which made the request) I'm not getting any returned JSON back in Postman...

**Traits/GetFact.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use App\Traits\ApiResponse;

trait GetFact {

    use ApiResponse;

    /**
     * Get random fact
     *
     * get random fact
     */
    public function getRandomFact () {
      $this->getFact();
      
      $this->apiResponse([
        'msg' => "Fact..."
      ], 200, true);
    }
}
```

**Traits/ApiResponse.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait ApiResponse {

    /**
     * API Response
     *
     * Return a JSON response for our API with params
     */
    public function apiResponse ($data, $code, $success = false) {
      return response()->json(array_merge(['success' => $success], $data), $code);
    }

}
```

**Controllers/FactController.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Traits\GetFact;

class FactsController extends Controller
{
    use GetFact;

    /**
     * Fact
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     */
    public function fact()
    {
        $this->getRandomFact()
    }

}
```

When I make my request to `/api/fact` I should be getting the returned JSON listed where I'm calling `$this->apiResponse()` with the `msg`, but I'm not? It's like the `return` doesn't seem to return JSON because it's scoped to the trait and not the controller and that there isn't a return in there? How can I achieve the listed.

Answer (score 0):

You are not "returning" anything from your Controller method. You have to return something for their to be a response with content. Also, `fact` and `getRandomFact` do not return anything so calling those isn't doing anything for you. You are also calling a `getFact` method and not assigning the return to anything (if it even returns anything).

Comment: If I add a `return` before `$this->getRandomFact()` it will prevent the rest of the code below it from executing, the above attached is purely a super slim version for concept. They do return something but missed out here. how do I essentially run `$this->getRandomFact()` from the controller, and get IT to return JSON??

Comment: you need to provide your actual code otherwise this is what happens, we can only go off of what you have shown .... but you just call that method and return the result ... so please update your code to something that is actually functional  `:)`